# Find the relation between the volumes of a cone and inscribed sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

I have a question that I've been working upon for a long time but in vain. Can you help me.
 Determine the relation between the volume of a con circumscribed to a regular tethadron and the volume of a sphere inscribed in tethadron.

What I tried to do is:![image]
[image]

You'll help me a lot! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working quickly, with tetrahedral edges 1 unit long, I found the base of the cone as $1\over\sqrt{3}$, the height of the cone as $\sqrt{2\over 3}$, and the radius of the sphere as $1\over 2\sqrt{3}$. If your answers differ, I'll redo it more carefully.

Comment: I have this following question. Can you please explain me why can we note the edges of tethadron as 1 unit long? May be the question is weird but since I don' t understand this can you give me a explanation, please?

Comment: It's not necessary. If you label the tetrahedron edge length $L$ Instead of 1, then all of my answers above should be multiplied by $L$. So, $L\over \sqrt{3}$, $L\sqrt{2\over 3}$, etc. I used $L =1$ because the answer to your question is a dimensionless ratio and $L$ will cancel out in the end anyway. (However when using $L=1$, one gives up the ability to "check units" by inspection during the calculation.)

Comment: THank you very, very much for your effort. Now I understood the idea, and also finally solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to understand what you're writing, because there're no words at all.
Can you do the following steps:

1) Find the height of the tetraedron as a function of its side

2) Find the radius if inscribed sphere as a function of the side of the tetraedron

3) Find the radius of the circle forming the base of the cone - still as a function of the side of the tetraedron

4) Find the volume of the cone

5) Find the volume of the inscribed sphere

6) Conclude.

If you have questions regarding any of the above steps, ask in comments.

Comment: Suggestion, make each tetrahedral edge 1 unit long.

Comment: Thank you , I'll try and come later with the result